# How to display custom sidebar in wordpress 5.5.2

Tags: plugins, functions, sidebar, register-sidebar

I am trying to display a custom sidebar in worpress 5.5.2 latest version but i have registered one sidebar in functions.php and in sidebar i want to display it so i put code to display in sidebar.php
but it's not going to display.

please anyone have idea then please help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: When asking for help with your code, you should include that code in your question so we can try to show you how to improve the code to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: okay but for this time I need to fix one issue in which I am developing a new theme from scratch and in that theme default sidebar is not enabled so I can't put widgets in that sidebar– Maarten00

Comment: You can also use get_the_sidebar() for adding sidebar in wordpress theme.